# Access the Filter Content in ng2-smart table

Tags: angular

Am using angular4. And I want to alert the filtered result of the ng2-smart-tabe column content.

How can I alert the user specified filter result...?

Or if there is any possibility of adding custom text-box at each column , for filtering in ng2-smart-table  with a separate function??

I tried to alert the filter content by adding a custom text like this.But it will not work...

```js
columns:{
    Name: {
        title: 'Name',
        type: 'string',
        filter: {
          type:'html',
          valuePreparedFunction:(cell,row)=>{
            return '<input type = "text" #search name="sname" (keydown.enter)="onSearch2(search.value)>'
          }
        }
      }
   }
```

Is there any possible way to crack the problem ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `filterFunction` attribute in the desired column, and do whatever you want. Here's an example for my filter function.

```
filterCountFunction(value?: any, search?: string): boolean {
    // value.name.includes(search)
    if (Object.keys(value).length === JSON.parse(search)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Used like this `filterFunction: this.filterCountFunction,`

Note: I define the settings inside the class with a method to make sure the data is avaiable

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fireService.getCompaniesList().subscribe((companies) => {
        this.companiesOptionsArray = companies.map(c => {
            return { value: c.name, title: c.name, key: c.key };
        });
        this.tableSettings = this.smartTableSettings();
    });
}
```